# I want to make a time calculator and, there is a need to read a single character, but I tried many way it won't work

Tags: c, generics

this is my program, this is not complete yet but, when I run this program, the single character reading part of it won't read, I checked without adding (&)ampersand. I tried many ways with arrays and so on, but I can't get the result. please help

```css
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int F,S,E,SM,EM;
    char t1,t2;

    //*S=starting time*//
    //*SM=start minute*//
    //*F=ending time*//
    //*FM=end minute*//

printf("\nEnter the start time: Hour : Minute");
scanf("%d %d",&S,&SM);
printf("\nEnter a  for AM Enter p for PM");
scanf(" %c",&t1);//problem
printf("\nEnter end time: Hour: Minute");
scanf("%d %d,",&E,&EM);
printf("\nEnter A for AM: Enter P for PM");
scanf(" %c ",&t2);//problem

return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: you could try using getchar() instead of scanf()

Comment: What kind of problem? Please describe your experience. How is the behaviour of the program different from what you expect?

Comment: I tried getchar and even gets to store a single character but all these does not working.

Comment: hrithik.k, Code does not output anything that was read.  Add code to print what was read.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanf()` will try to consume ALL the input, which means that the '\n' from pressing enter will carry over to the next scanf call. This is alleviated by you using a leading space character in your format `" %c"`. However, if the format of the input does not exactly match the actual input, i. e. format is `"%d %d"`, but the input is, say `" 1 1"`, scanf() will fail to write the format. I think this is why it's failing for you after compiling and testing out your code.

Consider adding some logging and error checking into this code snippet, so that it's easier to pin down these errors. Even something as simple as `printf("%d %d\n", S, SM);` after a scanf() call is much better than not tracking your results at all.